# Facebook graph api messaging permissions error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I need to send messages from a facebook page via graph api. I did it with post to '/:conversationId/messages' edge. But recently all my requests fail with error '#230 permissions disallow message to user' even though i didn't have it before. What shall i do to prevent this error?